# How to rediect unavailable pages to 404 using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have paste my htaccess file code How it possible to redirect unable file/folder,page,invalid searching not matching searching on 404.When i anything after url like ffsdfdfsdf or it may be anything that i see blank page.I know the problem is in htaccess file.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month”
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month”
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^floristnz\.co.nz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://floristnz.co.nz/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(florist)/(.*)$ florist_page.php?florist_name=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(florist)$ florist.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Buy-Flowers)$ Flowers.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(New-Baby)$ New-Baby.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Christmas-Flowers)$ Christmas-Flowers.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Flowers-With-Vases)$ Flowers-With-Vases.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Gift-Baskets)$ Gift-Baskets.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Plants)$ Plants.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Bouquets)$ Bouquets.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Arrangements)$ Arrangements.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^(Roses)$ Roses.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Sympathy)$ Sympathy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Celebration)$ Celebration.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Tropical-Flowers-And-Gifts)$ tropical-flowers-and-gifts.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Top-Ten-Online-Flowers)$ top-ten.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(Gifts)$ Gifts.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(contact)$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(article)/(.*)$ article.php?article_name=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(florists)/(.*)$ florist_listing.php?category_url=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(articles)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ article_listing.php?category_url=$2&page=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(articles)/(.*)$ article_listing.php?category_url=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(page)/(florist-article)$ florist_article.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(css)/(.*)$ css/$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(images)/(.*)$ images/$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^()$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(index.php)$ index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-_]+)$ static_page.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
Redirect 301 /florist/Oneroa http://floristnz.co.nz/florist/Oneroa%20Waiheke
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html/{ee:404}
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scripts:

- article.php
- florist_page.php
- florist_listing.php
- static_page.php

You need to check the parameters that's getting passed in and if they don't point to something meaningful (like an existing florist or existing page), then return a 404.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what means it  
You need to check the parameters that's getting passed in and if they don't point to something meaningful (like an existing florist or existing page)

Comment: @user3781881 Example: in `article.php`, you get the parameter `$_GET['article_name']`. Check to see if that article name exists, if not, return a 404.